# Why are many South Indian temple's walls painted in white and red stripes?

Tags: temple

In many south Indian temples, especially in Tamil Nadu and Andhra Pradesh, the temple's external walls are painted in white & red stripes. Why is it done so?

For example:

> [image: South Indian Temple wall]

Comment: May be that's just a fashion there.. I don't think there is any story behind that...

Comment: There might be some reason or at least some historical event behind that style. It seems to have become a part of South Indian culture. Here is a South Indian style temple in Germany which also has it's walls painted red & white: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hamm_Sri_Kamadchi_Ampal-Tempel.jpg Will see if anyone knows the reason :)

Comment: @RBK not every south indian temple have white and red stripes. Search for temples in karnatka and kerala

Comment: I have seen it in Andhra temples too. I agree I haven't seen it in Kerela or Karnataka. But my questions makes it clear. I've mentioned 'especially in Tamil Nadu' and Tamil Nadu is South India. I can't help if people choose to nitpick my question for 'errors'.

Comment: Red represent fire and white is purity. You burn your desire (vasanas) and gain purity. The sole's final abode is to merge with the supreme which we call God, whatever the religion may be.

Comment: Is this also found in shiva temples? Because the stripes could figuratively explain the viashnava namam

Answer (score 10):

Sri Kandadai Ramanujacharya [says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdaejVTYqms):

> **They are painted likewise nowadays so that temples can be identified from a long distance** & also to differentiate them from ordinary houses or buildings. But according to shastras, temples should be painted
> with seven colours. (**Saptha-varna-aashrithah.**)
>
> Lord likes color of Turmeric Powder (Yellow) most as Lord is
> Peetambarasali (who likes to be clad with Yellow garments). Lord
> also likes Kumkum color. So, Paramatma likes Yellow, [Kumkuma color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumkuma),
> White and Red in decreasing order. White represents Sattva
> Guna, Red represents Rajo Guna and Black represents Tamo Guna.
>
> **To  show these Gunas figuratively, most of temples are painted with White
> and Red as a person should have more Sattva and little Rajas and if
> possible no Tamas or very minute amount of Tamas.**

The video is part of [Dharma Sandhehalu](http://www.bhakthitv.in/category_dharmasandehalu.php) program which is telecast on Telugu Devotional channel [Bhakti TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhakthi_TV).