# Shri Ganesha's cloth color

Tags: ganesha

In the '*Ganapati Atharva Sheersha*', these shlokas describe him as --

> एकदन्तं चतुर्हस्तं पाशमङ्कुशधारिणम् ।
>   रदं च वरदं हस्तैर्बिभ्राणं मूषकध्वजम् ॥
>   रक्तं लम्बोदरं शूर्पकर्णकं **रक्तवाससम्** ।
>   रक्तगन्धानुलिप्ताङ्गं रक्तपुष्पैस्सुपूजितम् ॥

Here, "रक्तवाससम्" means He is wearing Red Garments (Rakta Vasam).

In the *Aarti (Marathi)* by *Samartha Ramdas Swami*, it is described as --

> लंबोदर **पीतांबर** फणिवरवंदना|
>   सरळ सोंड वक्रतुंड त्रिनयना|
>   दास रामाचा वाट पाहे सदना|
>   संकटी पावावे निर्वाणी रक्षावे सुरवरवंदना|

"पीतांबर" means yellow garment.

Since both the sources are authentic, I am in a dilemma as to which color should be taken into consideration.
Any hint?

Comment: He is God. He can wear as many colours as he want. ;-) Ganesha likes red and there is a reason for that. See a related question [Why Ganesha is covered with saffron(sindoor)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16579/5212). He is smeared with saffron when he is angry.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ,Thanks for your input. However, my question is very specific. Would appreciate if I can get answer wrt the Q. I totally agree with you that Lord Ganesha's energy is attracted with red colour, doorva, etc. But when "dhyanam" of any devata is concerned, the details are very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slokas are written by bhakthas or rishis who had a darshan/vision/dream of the devata on whom the sloka was then composed. Depending on the darsan they received, naturally the description will vary. Dhyana slokas precede a puja, aarti, sahasranama, homa etc. They are very specific and attempts to bring out a precise definition of the appearance of the devata. Thus a sloka creates a powerful image of the devata in the mind of the ritual performer to condense the divine life force. As per **Mudgala Purana**, there are [thirty two forms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-two_forms_of_Ganesha#cite_ref-Ramachandra_Rao,_p._vi_5-0) of Lord Ganesh. Of these, yoga ganapati and Sankata Hara Ganapati are wearing blue robes. In the famed "Suklambaradharam" dhyana sloka of Lord Ganesh, he is white robed. Therefore we can imagine Lord Ganesh as being dressed in the color which is prescribed by the dhyana sloka for that particular ritual being performed. All dhyana images can coexist and we can choose the one depending on dhyana sloka of the  ritual being performed.

Comment: Mudgala Purana seems little broad..can you please cite it's exact portion or provide a link to verify this?

Comment: Saadhu ! I got satisfactory explanation. Thanks @Tel ERT