# Colors of different varṇas: Is it their physical complexion or their qualities?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system, brahmins, kshatriya, color

From [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b015.htm), is this Mahābhārata śloka and its translation really talking about (physical) complexion of people belonging to the four varṇas or just their outward behavior? If it's the latter, what does 'red' or 'yellow' mean?

> 12,181.005a       brāhmaṇānāṃ sito varṇaḥ kṣatriyāṇāṃ tu lohitaḥ
>   12,181.005c      vaiśyānāṃ pītako varṇaḥ śūdrāṇām asitas tathā
>
> The complexion the Brahmanas obtained was **white**; that which the Kshatriyas obtained was **red**; that which the Vaisyas got was **yellow**; and that which was given to the Sudras was **black**.'

Comment: White represents Satva, Red represents Rajas and Black represents Tamas. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11225/3500). This further proves Guna based Varnasrama Dharma.

Answer (score 13):

These "colors" are to be understood metaphorically or allegorically as Gunas (qualities). As mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11225/3500), white represents Satva, Red represents Rajas and Black represents Tamas.

Furthermore, Bibek Debroy who translated the [BORI critical edition of Mahabharata](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh12_sa.html) says the same in his translation.

> ब्राह्मणानां **सितो** वर्णः क्षत्रियाणां तु **लोहितः** | 
>   वैश्यानां **पीतको** वर्णः शूद्राणा **मसितस्तथा** ||५||
>
> The complexion of brahmanas was **white**, while that of kshatriyas was
>   **red**. The complexion of vaishyas was **yellow**, while that of shudras was
>   **black**.

In Footnotes, he says

> It is possible that this is meant to be taken figuratively and not
>   literally. Brahmanas possessed the sattva quality, kshatriyas
>   possessed the rajas quality, vaishyas possessed a combination of
>   sattva and rajas and shudras possessed the tamas quality.

In succeding lines Bharadvaja Muni asks, how Varna (complexion) alone decides distinction?

> भरद्वाज उवाच||
>
> चातुर्वर्ण्यस्य वर्णेन यदि **वर्णो** विभज्यते | सर्वेषां खलु वर्णानां
>   दृश्यते वर्णसङ्करः ||६||
>
> “Bharadvaja said, ‘If the distinction between the four varnas is only
>   on the basis of **complexion** and that is how the varnas are to be
>   differentiated, then it is evident and can be seen that among the
>   varnas, there has been a mixture of varnas.
>
> कामः क्रोधो भयं लोभः शोकश्चिन्ता क्षुधा श्रमः | सर्वेषां नः प्रभवति
>   कस्माद्वर्णो विभज्यते ||७||
>
> Desire, anger, fear, avarice, sorrow, anxiety, hunger and exhaustion
>   influence everyone. How can varnas be differentiated on the basis of
>   this?

To this, Brigu Muni explains how Dvaijas (Dvi =  two ; Ja = related to birth : Twice born, translated as Brahmanas) changed their Varnas by changing their Gunas (turned to other Varnas by their Karma).

> भृगुरुवाच||
>
> न विशेषोऽस्ति वर्णानां सर्वं ब्राह्ममिदं जगत् | 
>  ब्रह्मणा
>   पूर्वसृष्टं हि **कर्मभिर्वर्णतां गतम्** ||१०||
>
> Bhrigu replied, ‘There is no special difference between the varnas.
>   Everything in this universe first consisted of brahmanas. Brahma
>   created all of them earlier and **they attained varnas because of
>   their deeds.**
>
> **कामभोगप्रियास्तीक्ष्णाः क्रोधनाः** प्रियसाहसाः | 
>  त्यक्तस्वधर्मा
>   **रक्ताङ्गास्ते** द्विजाः क्षत्रतां गताः ||११||
>
> There were Dvijas (brahmanas) who loved **desire and objects of pleasure**.
>   They were fierce and angry and loved courage. They abandoned their own
>   dharma and having turned **red** in their limbs, became kshatriyas.
>
> गोषु वृत्तिं समाधाय पीताः कृष्युपजीविनः | 
>  स्वधर्मं नानुतिष्ठन्ति
>   ते द्विजा वैश्यतां गताः ||१२||
>
> There were Dvijas (brahmanas) who earned a living from animal husbandry and
>   subsisted on agriculture. They did not follow their own dharma, turned
>   yellow and became vaishyas.
>
> **हिंसानृतप्रिया लुब्धाः** सर्वकर्मोपजीविनः | 
>  **कृष्णाः**
>   शौचपरिभ्रष्टास्ते द्विजाः शूद्रतां गताः ||१३||
>
> There were Dvijas (brahmanas) **who loved violence and falsehood.** They were
>   avaricious and turned to all kinds of deeds to earn a living. They
>   were dislodged from purity, turned **black** and became shudras.
>
> In this way, depending on their deeds, **brahmanas became other
>   varnas**.

More importantly, Shvetashvatara Upanishad of Krishna Yajurveda defines Prakriti as Red-white-Black which are interpreted as Rajas-Satva-Tamas.

> अजामेकां **लोहितशुक्लकृष्णां** बह्वीः प्रजाः सृजमानां सरूपाः 
> ।  अजो
>   ह्येको जुषमाणोऽनुशेते जहात्येनां भुक्तभोगामजोऽन्यः ॥ ५॥
>
> There is one unborn prakriti−**red, white and black**−which gives
>   birth to many creatures like  itself. An unborn individual soul
>   becomes attached to it and enjoys it, while another unborn individual
>   soul leaves it after his enjoyment is completed.

Adishankara says

> Prakriti (nature) creates many creatures like itself which are
>   governed by three Gunas - sattva, rajas and tamas - called red, white
>   and black in this Mantra.

Furthermore while explaining Brahmasutras, Adi Shankara [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34119.htm),

> For, he says, we have the following mantra (Sve. Up. IV, 5), 'There is
>   one agâ 1, red, white, and black, producing manifold offspring of the
>   same nature. There is one agâ who loves her and lies by her; there is
>   another who leaves her after having enjoyed her.'--In this mantra the
>   words 'red,' 'white,' and 'black' denote the three constituent
>   elements of the pradhâna. **Passion is called red on account of its
>   colouring, i.e. influencing property; Goodness is called white,
>   because it is of the nature of Light; Darkness is called black on
>   account of its covering and obscuring property**. The state of equipoise
>   of the three constituent elements, i.e. the pradhâna, is denoted by
>   the attributes of its parts, and is therefore called red-white-black.

[Vajrasuchika Upanishad](http://www.australiancouncilofhinduclergy.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/vajra_suchika_upanishad.pdf) of Sama Veda says Brahmana is the one who has attained self realization and it also says Varna doesn't depend on color, birth or body.

> tarhi deho brāhmaṇa iti cet tan na | ācaṇḍālādi padantānām manuṣyāṇām
>   pañcabhautikatvena dehasaikarūpatvāt |
>   jarā-maraṇa-dharmādharmādi-samya darśanāt **|brāhmaṇas śveta-varṇaḥ |
>   kṣatriyo rakta-varṇaḥ | vaiśya pīta-varṇaḥ | śūdraḥ kṛṣṇa varṇa iti
>   niyamābhāvāt** | pitrādi dahane putrādīnām brahma hatyādi
>   doṣasambhavācca | tasmān na deho brāhmaṇa iti || 5 ||
>
> Then is the body the Brahmin? No, it is not so, because the body which
>   is composed of the five elements, is the same in all classes of human
>   beings down to the chandalas (outcastes), etc. And it is also observed
>   that old age and death, virtue [dharma] and vice [adharma] are found
>   to be common to all human beings. **There is also no absolute
>   distinction (in the complexion of the four classes) that the Brahmin
>   is of the white complexion, that the Kshatriya is of the red
>   complexion, that the Vaishya is of the tawny complexion, that the
>   Sudra is of the dark complexion.** [If the body is the brahmin] the
>   sons and other kinsmen would becoming guilty of the murder of a
>   Brahmin and other (sins) on cremating the bodies of their fathers and
>   other kinsmen. Therefore the body is not the Brahmin.

So, these colors represent Gunas.

Comment: and furthermore these verses can't be taken literally.. if we talk in literal way then Krishna, Vedavyasa, Yadavas were all black.. so it certainly represents Gunas... Furthermore it is confirmed in Shrutis also.. like The Svetasvatara Upanishad 4.5 state " There is one unborn prakriti− **red, white and black** −which gives birth to many creatures like
itself." Thus these colours represents Gunas of Prakirti ie. Satva, Rajas and Tamas.

Comment: So 'yellow' & 'red' are actual colors? Complexion usually means "the natural color, texture, and appearance of a person's skin, especially of the face." I don't see any yellow people anywhere ;)

Comment: @sv. Complexion also means "the general aspect or character of something".

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, but that's the secondary meaning.

Comment: @sv. No. Not actual colors. They allude to Gunas or nature of person.

Comment: Yes the Upanishads also associate Agni-apas-Prithvi with Red-white -black colors..They represent the 3 gunas

Comment: "**turned black** and became shudras", "**turned red** in their **limbs**, became kshatriyas" --- I think it means **both** color and guna, not guna alone.

Comment: @sv. That's not correct. By Skin color, how can we decide Guna? We can't generalize.

Comment: @sv. Updated the answer from Vajrasuchika upanishad which says skin color has nothing to do with Varna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I read Vajrasuchika Upanishad you linked, it's a good one, but its conclusion is who has realized brahman is a brahmin not even guna based. ("The concluding section of the Upanishad makes it clear that not until one has realized the Supreme Being can one be called a Brahmin.")

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer . So SHudras can be white colour I mean skin colour right I mean literally??

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Yes