# What would be the varna of son born out of Ugra father & Kshatriya Woman?

Tags: caste-system, dharma-shastras, smriti, manu-smriti

What would be the Varna of a son born out of Ugra father & Kshatriya mother?

From *Manu smriti chapter 10*

> **From a Kshatriya and the daughter of a Sudra springs a being, called Ugra**, resembling both a Kshatriya and a Sudra, ferocious in his manners, and delighting in cruelty.

Comment: When mother is of higher caste that is kshatriya in this case the progeny would be a pratiloma mixed caste(also considered outcaste) e.g. Suta is a son of Bramhin Mother and Kshatriya Father. They are not in the standard varna system, Shastras assign special work for them like Sutas are assigned work of charioteer http://www.importantindia.com/2834/anuloma-and-pratiloma-marriage/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the son has to be called an **outcaste**(i.e one  without any varna) as said by Yogi in comments.

Because the castes are only 4 in number and there is no fifth caste.So one who does not belong to any of the 4 has to be treated as belonging to no caste .Or to be born in a confused caste(that is difficult or impossible to determine).

> Manu Smriti 10.4. Brahmana, the Kshatriya, and the Vaisya castes
>   (varna) are the twice-born ones, but the fourth, the Sudra, has one
>   birth only; **there is no fifth (caste)**.

When marriages take place between the same castes its easy to determine the caste of the progeny & which is the same as that of the father.

> Manu Smriti 10.5. In all castes (varna) those (children) only which
>   are begotten in the direct order on wedded wives, equal (in caste and
>   married as) virgins, are to be considered as belonging to the same
>   caste (as their fathers)

However,in cases where the father is one caste higher than the mother's caste then the son will be called as "anantaras" and he will belong to one caste lower than that of the father.

> 10.6. Sons, begotten by twice-born man on wives of the next lower castes, they declare to be similar (to their fathers, but) blamed on
>   account of the fault (inherent) in their mothers
>
> 10.14. **Those sons of the twice-born, begotten on wives of the next lower castes,** who have been enumerated in due order, **they call by the
>   name Anantaras (belonging to the next lower caste),** on account of the
>   blemish (inherent) in their mothers.
>
> Manu Smriti 10.24. **By** adultery (committed by persons) of (different)
>   castes, by **marriages with women who ought not to be married,** and by
>   the neglect of the duties and occupations (prescribed) to each, are
>   **produced (sons who owe their origin) to a confusion the castes**

So,an Ugra is already an outcaste.And on cohabiting with a Kshatriya woman he will create another kind of outcaste or a confused caste progeny.

However,there is this following verse,which says,as far as duties are concerned,an Ugra can be treated as a Sudra also.

> 10.41. Six sons, begotten (by Aryans) on women of equal and the next lower castes (Anantara), have the duties of twice-born men; **but all
>   those born in consequence of a violation (of the law) are, as regards
>   their duties, equal to Sudras.**

So,treating an Ugra as a Sudra ,the son in question can also be called a **Kshattri:**

> Manu Smriti 10.16. **From a Sudra spring in the inverse order (by
>   females of the higher castes)** three base-born (sons, apasada), an
>   Ayogava, **a Kshattri**, and a Kandala, the lowest of men

So,basically,the son has to be called an outcaste or a base-born(apasada).And,as far as his duties are concerned he can take upon Sudra's duties.

His prescribed duties are also specified by Manu as follows:

> Manu Smriti 10.49. **To Kshattris, Ugras,** and Pukkasas, **catching and
>   killing (animals) living in holes**; to Dhigvanas, working in leather;
>   to Venas, playing drums

Comment: Is Varnashram based on birth only?

Comment: Many will say NO..They will say It is based on Guna also or even Guna only..In that case will ur question make any sense?..I mean how to determine the son's Varna then without knowing his gunas?

Comment: I'm confused about Varnashram. how can anyone confirm he had no any outcaste forefather in eternal chain ?

Comment: The way a Ugra is born implies that he does not belong to any of the 4 castes..His sons caste will be out caste only..Now different outcastes are named in Manu Smriti..But those are just names to differentiate one from the other..All of them are having no caste only and are generally called as low borns..

Comment: Yes @RickRoss. But Gautam Buddha rejected Vedas saying he believed original Vedas, he said current scriptures are distorted ones. What say ?

Comment: I admit there seems no possible way to differentiate people if caste is based on Gunas, but I have seen Brahmin behaving like Shudras & Shudras behaving like Brahmin. Then don't you think birth based casteism has flaws ?

Comment: You can ask separate questions about twice-borns who are that by birth but not according to their karmas..I may have answers for those questions..

Comment: @user367180 Scriptures also support Guna based Varnasrama Dharma. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16675/3500). btw, i'm strong believer of Guna based Varnasrama Dharma than birth based one.

Comment: @Rickross Can we follow Manusmriti in Kali Yuga, as Parashara Smriti is recommended Smriti for Kali Yuga?

Comment: First time read the name such Smriti.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Manu Smriti is still valid unless its contradicted in Parashara..This is the way i see it..There are some rules which are valid all throughout the ages..Give u an example..In Manu its stated sin can be transferred through conversation,touch etc but in Parashara its clearly mentioned that in Kali sin is incurred only when one commits it..it can't be incurred thru touch etc..So in that case and other similar cases we have to go with Parashara...And many smritis quote Manu often even Parashara quotes Manu many a times..

Comment: Nice answer Rickross Ji. 3 doubts though. Kindly help. 1)Purusha Sukta speaks only of 4 Varnas. Now according to Manu 10.41 can we include Chandalas among Sudras? 2) Janmajayate Sudra everyone is born as Sudra only right...then how can someone be called outside of 4 varnas? He is of nature of Sudra only right ? 3) When Shastras say all varnas desire happyness all varnas are eligible to perform so and so act...can the Chandalas also be included?

Comment: As far as duties are considered they are equal to Sudras. Only this much is said in 10.41@SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Answer (score 5):

**Such a person is called a Kshota.**. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=o21pAAAAcAAJ&dq=kshota&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q=kshota&f=false) is what Vachaspati Mishra's Vivada Chintamani says:

> The son of a Sudra mother and kshatriya father is called ugra.  The son of a kshatriya mother and ugra father is called kshota.

Vachaspati Mishta, by the way, was an early Advaita Acharya and one of the most famous commentators on Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya.