# Did Satyavati and Shantanu belong to same caste?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system

Shantanu was king of Hastinapura. So, clearly, he is Kshatriya by both caste and Varna.

Coming to Satyavati, she was the daughter of Chedi king Vasu and cursed apsara-turned-fish Adrika and brought up as the adopted daughter of a fisherman-chieftain Dusharaj on the banks of the river Yamuna. So, Satyavati is Kshatriya by Varna and non-Kshatriya by caste.

If the above two statements are true, then their marriage is inter-caste. Is it true?

Otherwise, how can they belong to the same caste?

Comment: Not sure how they belong to same caste, but there are many examples of inter-caste marriages in Hindu ancient history including pre-marital association of satyavati with sage parashar then gave birth to sage ved-vyasa

Comment: @CR241 Did Satyavati hide her union with Parashar towards Shantanu?

Comment: What is this strange distinction between caste and varna? They are the same.

Comment: What ever Shantanu only know s the truth.. may or may not? but there are many pre-marital and post-marital affairs in Mahabharatha. I believe she didn't hind her past based on this statement "In Mahabharata, Vyasa's mother marries the king of Hastinapur and gives birth to two sons. Both the sons die and their wives are left with no children. She asks him to impregnate both the wives"

Comment: @moonstar2001 Varna based on family and are only 4. But caste is based on work and are many.

Comment: There is no such distinction @hanugm. If that was the case, then it applies only to the 4th varna, which is false.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Then why Draupadi  rejected Karna stating 'Suta putra'?

Comment: You are answering your own Q :-) if he was suta putra  , then his "caste" according to your definition should have been kshatriya because he was a warrior. No? His occupation did not carry much significance in the case of matrimony. He was raised by a charioteer. His birth was not well known to all. Interestingly, the word sUta means both "charioteer" and "sun" in Sanskrit. So, draupadi, because she is agnisambhava, did indeed speak with truth.

Comment: According to my definition in question, im thinking Karna's caste as SUTA but his Varna is Kshetriya, So, Inorder to avoid inter-caste marriage, she rejected KARNA.  I edited Q. Previously I wrote Shudra

Comment: So, she is not referring Karna's caste, but father's name!

Comment: Above you say caste is based on work and varna on family. Below you say the opposite.  Of course, she didn't want an intercaste marriage. Because though he is a warrior he is perceived as someone belonging to a different caste/varna. So, varna/caste is based on birth. It looks like you are very confused about varna/caste. Just stick to one word and one definition. This whole birth vs occupation is not accurate.

Comment: Sorry, Yeah, I am pretty confused, and I am not getting why such great person(Draupadhi) gave value to caste than skills

Comment: "Draupadi rejected Karna stating Suta putra" - not true, read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16148/2995).

Comment: @sv. So, according to the official story 1, Draupadi gave value to caste than skills.

Comment: Yes, but Story #2 is more plausible because the Pandavas themselves were disguised as brahmanas and Draupadi did not ask them their jaati or profession. Also, it appears Karna did try his hand at the swayamvara so your conclusion 'Draupadi gave value to caste than skills' is not completely true. The critical edition of the MB has several contradictions, so to reach a definite conclusion you've to analyze all accounts of the same story.

Comment: Satyavati was born to King, so she was kshatriya woman brought up by a fisherman

Comment: @hanugm, vyasa was avatara, born as 16 year old.. not regular human baby born from mother's womb, so parashara and saytavati were 'vyaja' or 'excuse' for lila of God being born to them.. neither parashara lost his brahmacharya, not satyavati lost her kannika because of the union. if anyone says otherwise, they are ignorant of divine lilas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Did Satyavatī and Śantanu belong to the same caste (birth-based varṇa)?

No. Śantanu was a kṣatriya and Satyavatī a śūdra.

---

#### Satyavatī's biological parents

- Father - Uparicara Vasu (a king, most likely a kṣatriya king)
- Mother - Adrikā (a fisher-woman, so most likely an outcaste or śūdra)

Here's the [official birth story of Satyavatī](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01064.htm) from the Mahābhārata:

> And the king [Uparicara Vasu] became possessed with desire, and he saw not his wife before him. Maddened by desire he was roaming hither and thither, when he saw a beautiful Asoka decked with dense foliage, its branches covered with flowers. And the king sat at his ease in the shade of that tree. And excited by the fragrance of the season and the charming odours of the flowers around, and excited also by the delicious breeze, the king could not keep his mind away from the thought of the beautiful Girika. And beholding that a swift hawk was resting very near to him, the king, acquainted with the subtle truths of Dharma and Artha, went unto him and said, 'Amiable one, carry thou this seed (semen) for my wife Girika and give it unto her. Her season hath arrived.'
>
> The hawk, swift of speed, took it from the king and rapidly coursed through the air. While thus passing, the hawk was seen by another of his species. Thinking that the first one was carrying meat, the second one flew at him. The two fought with each other in the sky with their beaks. While they were fighting, the seed fell into the waters of the Yamuna. And in those waters dwelt an Apsara of the higher rank, known by the name of **Adrika, transformed by a Brahmana's curse into a fish**. As soon as Vasu's seed fell into the water from the claws of the hawk, Adrika rapidly approached and swallowed it at once. That fish was, some time after, caught by the fishermen. And it was the tenth month of the fish's having swallowed the seed. **From the stomach of that fish came out a male and a female child of human form.** The fishermen wondered much, and wending unto king Uparichara (for they were his subjects) told him all. They said, 'O king, these two beings of human shape have been found in the body of a fish!' The male child amongst the two was taken by Uparichara. That child afterwards became the virtuous and truthful monarch Matsya.
>
> After the birth of the twins, the Apsara herself became freed from her curse. For she had been told before by the illustrious one (who had cursed her) that she would, while living in her piscatorial form, give birth to two children of human shape and then would be freed from the curse. Then, according to these words, having given birth to the two children, and been killed by the fishermen, she left her fish-form and assumed her own celestial shape. The Apsara then rose up on the path trodden by the Siddhas, the Rishis and the Charanas.
>
> The fish-smelling daughter of the Apsara in her piscatorial form was then given by the king unto the fishermen, saying, 'Let this one be thy daughter.' **That girl was known by the name of Satyavati**. And gifted with great beauty and possessed of every virtue, she of agreeable smiles, owing to contact with fishermen, was for some time of the fishy smell. Wishing to serve her (foster) father she plied a boat on the waters of the Yamuna.

Now if you are like me and find a part of the above story (i.e., a fish getting pregnant by simply swallowing human seed and then delivering a pair of human babies) unbelievable, [this article](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/uparichara-vasu) offers a more rational explanation:

> This was the strangest myths I could find in Mahabharata. It reveals how imaginative these people were and how they entwine ignorance and imagination into such deadly cocktail. At least some of the ancient people believed that babies are born with the sole contribution from men. They considered women as mere vessels to carry the babies of men. It was unknown to them that to develop an embryo contribution from both man and woman are needed. A fish after swallowing semen delivering babies! Below is a plausible reconstruction of what might have happened.
>
> **Adrika was a maiden belonging to the Matsya (fishermen) tribe and Vasu beget two children in her, probably when he was away from his wife Girika.** Adrika was described as an Apsara, due to her beauty. Apsaras were mentioned as extremely beautiful. The word 'Apsara' can be divided into 'Apa' (water) and Sara (lakes). They were often described as women seen in the vicinity of water-bodies like lakes and rivers. A Matsya lady (fisher-women) too lives close to water-bodies like seas, lakes and rivers. There are also myths about fairies called Matsya-Kanyakas (fish-women / fisher-women) who were half fish and half woman. Such tales were also similar to the tales of Apsaras. Thus Matsya Kanyakas and Apsaras seems to be same. Both these terms later assumed the meaning of fairies living close to water bodies, and Apsaras in particular was formerly their tribal name. Fisher-women were the Apsaras and the Apsaras were the fisher-women.
>
> Adrika probably died while delivering the twin babies. Death of women after delivering babies, especially twins, were quite common in those days. **The fishermen after learning about the affair between Adrika and the king might have taken the babies to the palace.**
>
> ...

#### Satyavatī's caste

Assuming Satyavatī was born to a Kṣatriya father (Uparicara) and a Śūdra mother (Adrikā), she must be an Ugra<sup>1</sup>. And because an Ugra doesn't fit into any of the four castes<sup>2</sup>, she's an outcaste. However, for all practical purposes she can be considered a Śūdra<sup>3</sup>.

> <sup>1</sup> From the Kṣatriya on a Śūdra maiden is born a being called ‘Ugra,’ of the stuff of the Kṣatriya and Śūdra, cruel in his deeds and dealings. [[Manu 10.9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201742.html)]
>
> <sup>2</sup> The Brāhmaṇa, the Kṣatriya and the Vaiśya are the three twice-born castes; the fourth is the one caste, Śūdra; there is no fifth. [[Manu 10.4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201736.html)]
>
> <sup>3</sup> Six sons born on women of the same caste and of those of the next lower castes partake of the character of ‘twice-born’ persons. But all those born of violation have been declared to be of the nature of Śūdras. [[Manu 10.41](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201771.html)]

#### Śantanu's caste

From [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01096.htm), Śantanu appears to be a pure Kṣatriya (i.e., no intermixing of castes):

> And Pratipa married Sunanda, the daughter of Sivi, and begat upon her three sons, viz., Devapi, Santanu and Valhika. And Devapi, while still a boy, entered the woods as a hermit. And Santanu became king.

Comment: I especially liked the way u ascertained Satyavati's caste. I remember these verses as i have used them in my answers.

Comment: Your answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16890/2995) was really helpful in writing this answer!

Comment: Oh that's good to know.

Comment: @Rickross, where exactly do scriptures say that Adrika is a Sudra ? Also, the second part is opinionated "Thus Matsya Kanyakas and Apsaras seems to be same"

Comment: @Rickross, by that logic, the sons of Satyavati (being an Ugra) - Chitrangadha and Vichitraveerya should also be considered 'Ugras' (or lesser), hence they should have had no right to the throne, but that's not the case. By extension, neither should Dhritarashtra or Pandu, because Vichitraveerya's very marriage to Ambika/Ambalika (Kshatriya women) would have been Pratiloma. If you argue that none followed varna rules at that time, then by extension, if Dhritarashtra was blind and Pandu was in forest/dead, Vidura could have been crowned king. But again, that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 5):

Satyavati was born to a King, so she was Kshatriya woman brought up by a fisherman.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyavati):

> Daughter of the Chedi king Vasu (also known as Uparichara Vasu) and a
>   cursed apsara (celestial nymph)-turned-fish Adrika, Satyavati was
>   brought up as a commoner – the adopted daughter of a
>   fisherman-chieftain Dusharaj(who was also a ferryman) on the banks of
>   the river Yamuna

Answer (score 4):

It is allowed for a female to marry a male of a higher caste as per the Manusmriti. It is not allowed for a female to marry into a lower caste and thereby reduce her caste.

> 12. For the first marriage of twice-born
>       men (wives) of equal caste are recommended; but
>       for those who through desire proceed (to marry again)
>       the following females, (chosen) according to the (direct)
>       order (of the castes), are most approved.
> 13. It is declared that a Sudra woman alone (can be) the wife of
>       a Sudra, she and one of his own caste (the wives) of a
>       Vaisya, those two and one of his own caste (the wives)
>       of a Kshatriya, those three and one of his own caste (the
>       wives) of a Brahmana.

So it was valid for Draupadi (a Kshatriya) to marry those who were considered Brahmins (and there are many such cases of Sages marrying daughters of Kings).

Similarly it was considered valid for Satyavati (as long as she's not a Brahmin) to marry Shantanu, a Kshatriya.

Source: essentially any translation of Manusmriti. I used http://www.hindubooks.org/manusmriti.pdf

Comment: Satyavati was born to a King, so she was kshatriya woman brought up by a fisherman

Comment: @ram could u provide a link to the whole story of Satyavati being born to a king? I know she was the daughter of the chief of fishermen but nothing beyond that.

Comment: see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyavati)

Comment: @ram got it from your answer. As an extension, is that compendium of puranas by Mani a valid resource and sourced from the original puranas? Asking mainly to include that into my list of reading materials.

Comment: what do u mean by "compendium of puranas by Mani" - Manu dharma shastra is its own separate scripture derived from kalpa sutras, which is one of the 6 vedangas

Comment: @ram The wikipedia link you mentioned is derived from a compendium of Puranas written by a person called 'Mani'.

Answer (score 2):

i don't see a clear difference here between varna and caste here. the vedas are filled with examples of people of all castes/varnas being cursed into abominable life forms but they always kept their caste. in fact, the higher caste personality being forced to hang out with the lower caste society was the pain that came with the curse.[Ref: Society and Religion: From Rugveda to Puranas
By Jayant Gadkari]

Remember, Sage Parashar( the sage who could look into the skies and mentally calculate your Kundali in his mind and give perfect astro-predictions) saw Satyavati, he decided to produce Vyas with her because of her high caste(varna) hidden behind her fisher-women body smell.[Ref :Bhattacharya, Pradip (May–June 2004). "Of Kunti and Satyawati: Sexually Assertive Women of the Mahabharata"]