# Does varna mean color?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti, varna

I came across a post of an atheist page on facebook that stated that "***varna*** means color, so varna might attribute to **color** **based** **discrimination** along side cast based discrimination" is that true?

Comment: This may be related a bit but not 100% true..Arjuna's color was dark but he was Kashtriya and not Shudra..

Comment: Arjuna, as, ā, or ī, am, white, clear, the colour
of day; of silver; (as), m. the white colour .  arjuna is cognate with latin argentum (silver).

Comment: @SK May be u r talking about some other Arjuna..Here is what Arjuna said "Krishna, my tenth appellation, was given to me by my father out of affection towards his **black-skinned boy** of great purity.' - http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04044.htm So as per my little understanding he was black-skinned...and not only Arjuna but also Draupadi was of darkish complexion (thats why Krishnaa is her another name)..

Comment: Varna can mean color, the 4 varnas and also the alphabets like Swaravarna, Vyanjanvarna etc..

Comment: Related or duplicate of [Colors of different varṇas: Is it their physical complexion or their qualities?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16672/3500)

Comment: @yds - the English in your citation is wrong.  Here Krishna means "attractive".

Answer (score 5):

Varna can mean color but has no connection with any discrimination. Varna can not be translated as caste either.

> Vaisampayana said,’ Hearing these words of Arjuna, O chastiser of
>   foes, Nakula of mighty arms and a broad chest, temperate in speech and
>   possessed of great wisdom, **with face whose colour then resembled that
>   of copper,** looked at the king ….’

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section Xii

Mahabharata says the following about Draupadi.

> Yudhisthira answered the chief of the deities once more, saying, - ‘O
>   conqueror of Daityas, I venture not to dwell anywhere, separated from
>   them. I desire to go there where my brothers have gone. I wish to go
>   there where that foremost of women, Draupadi, of ample proportions and
>   **darkish complexion** and endued with great intelligence and righteous of
>   conduct, has gone.’

Mahabharata Mahaprasthanika Parva Section III

Neither Nakula nor Draupadi were Shudras.